# Bevel Modifier On A Solidified Plane Doesn't Work

Tags: mesh, modifiers, bevel

To fix this I followed step by step the blender guru tutorial on how to make a chair, but I failed.
There's my object,[image]

Comment: Hello, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Apply all transforms before applying the solidify modifier